# Bluemix, SSO: Calling REST service from mobile app (public client, native application)

Tags: web-services, oauth, client, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have a Bluemix web application (Liberty for Java), which implements some web services. These web services should be called from a mobile application (Android). I have now secured this web application by binding it to the Bluemix Single Sign On service (SSO) with a cloud directory created in the SSO service. Using the web app from a web browser works fine; but, I have problems obtaining an access token from the SSO service, which would allow the mobile application to invoke the services.

From the OAuth2 specification ([IETF RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)), I figured that the appropriate way of doing this would be the "native application" profile with a "public client" (as specified in Clause 2.1 of the OAuth2 Spec) using the "password" grant type (OAuth2 spec, Clause 4.3 "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant").

I used the Spring for Android framework for this purpose, and code for this would look like this:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails =
    new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setId("dtu-se2-e15-cloud-directory");
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(APP_SSO_API_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI);
resourceDetails.setClientId(APP_SSO_API_CLIENT_ID);
resourceDetails.setClientSecret(APP_SSO_API_CLIENT_SECRET);
resourceDetails.setGrantType("password");
resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList(SCOPE));
resourceDetails.setUsername(USERNAME);
resourceDetails.setPassword(PASSWORD);

OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails); 
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

UserPosition newPosition = restTemplate.postForObject(
    POST_POSITION_SERVICE_URI, position, UserPosition.class);
```

But, I don't think that this code matters, and ultimately made my experiments with obtaining access tokens directly with curl:

Actually, I tried using two different clients with different OAuth2 token endpoints:

- I created a client (and client credentials) in the Cloud directory, that I had created in the Bluemix SSO service. And I tried the OAuth2 Token Endpoint URI and the created client credentials. But it appears that this endpoint does not support the grant type "password" at all. It appears that this client is not considered a public client by the endpoint.
- I also tried the credentials and OAuth Token Endpoint URI for the Web application itself (which I looked up in the *VCAP_SERVICES* environment variable). This end point seems to support the grant type "password"; but all variants of requests I could think of, kept responding: *invalid_resource_owner_credential*.

As I said, I used curl to try out many different variations of requests to these
token endpoints:

- used the token endpoint URI of both the SSO services with the web app credentials
  as well as the one created in the cloud directory API Access
- tried GET and POST (did not make any difference)
- tried *Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded* and
  *Content-Type: application/json* (both of them seemed to work with the same effect)
- providing the client_id only (which always was unsuccessful)
- providing the client credentials in the body or parameters, as well as
  authenication information in the header (actually, I do not like the idea
  of providing the client secret to the Android app, but I tried that too);
- as user name, I tried the name as I had created it in the web browser redirection
  when registering a new user; but I also tried the user name which the Principal of
  the security context of a request would provide (when successfully invoking
  a service from a web browser with the user logged in); I even tried the principal's
  accessId (non of these worked, I always got: *invalid_resource_owner_credential*)
- used different scopes, and none at all

None of the above (and different combinations of that) would result in a successful
response and an access token for the user. The "best" I could get was a response
*invalid_resource_owner_credential* (making me believe that at least the client was
accepted in some situations).

Unfortunately, I did not find many things that could be configured concerning client
access (and public clients, in particular), and I did not find much documentation on
which subset of the OAuth2 protocol (grant types and profiles) is supported by the
Bluemix SSO service and the attached cloud directory.

Can anyone could tell me how to authenticate with a Bluemix web application
(Liberty for Java) from a mobile app (Android) as a public client or how to set
up the Bluemix web app and the SSO service to which it is bound so that this is
possible. In case it would matter, I am working with Bluemix in the "US South"
region and under an IBM Academic Initiative membership account for Bluemix.

I would prefer a solution, where the mobile app would not need to know the client
secret, but if this is the only way to make this work for now, adding the client
credentials to the mobile app would be OK.

I would appreciate any help with this problem, thanks in advance,

Ekkart

Comment: This scenario is not currently supported by Bluemix SSO service. It's in the roadmap. What's your time frame to get this implemented?

Comment: Thanks for the information. This was needed for some student projects in the context of one of my courses; the concrete student projects are finished -- using some workarounds. But, I will probably continue these projects in autumn 2016 (and probably need this functionality for other student projects too). So having this feature by August 2016 would be great. And I am  pretty sure many others could use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix has a mobile-specific service called Mobile Client Access that could help to facilitate security for your mobile app.  To read about it, log into Bluemix and look for it under the Mobile category.  To ask questions about it here, use or search using the [bluemix-mobile-services] tag.